# Errors in Swift initialisers

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2

What is the best way to handle an `init` that might fail in `Swift`? For example, you create an instance of class that depends on a certain resource that might not be available.

Apparently we have 2 options:

- A bailable init that returns nil (the Cocoa way)
- An init that throws an error

See below

```
enum ThingError: ErrorType{
    case crap
}
class Thing {
    init(c: Int) throws{
        if c < 0 {
            throw ThingError.crap
        }
    }
}



var c = try Thing(c: 3)

do{
    var d = try Thing(c: -4)
}catch{
    print("oh vey!")
}
```

Is there a recommended way of doing this?  The second option seems more "Swifty"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither is inherently better or Swiftier.

Personally I find `throws` initializers a huge pain. I'd much rather have a failed initializer return `nil`, because then I can do my initialization with `guard let` instead of having to wrap things in `do/catch` and deal with the resulting scoping issues. Your code illustrates the problem; your `var d` is "stuck" inside a `do` scope. I'd rather say this:

```
guard let d = Thing(c:-4) else {return}
// now d is unwrapped and in scope!
```

...than this (what you have to say):

```
do {
    var d = try Thing(c: -4)
} catch {
    print("oh vey!")
}
// and here there is no `d`, so _now_ what?
```

On the other hand, throwing an error offers an opportunity to send a message, i.e. to be *communicative* about exactly what went wrong. You can't do that with a mere `init?` initializer; it works or it fails, and that's all the caller knows.

Comment: "how many times does one come across an init that can fail in multiple ways" All the time, @Grimxn. I thought of `initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` instantly, and there are lots and lots of others. That is exactly why, in Objective-C, such methods have an `error:` pointer parameter. That parameter tells you _how_ we failed.

Comment: "that most inits fail in zero or one ways, and single failures should use failable..." And that, @Grimxn, I believe, is what my answer _said_, no?

Comment: You're right - I'm adding nothing here, other than documenting my own slow comprehension. Add your comment examples to the answer, and I'll delete my comments.